# JTable color row and cell dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to make a search functionality for JTable object. 
I have a JTextFiled where i put my text to search.
I want to change colors rows and cells which contains this text.
Now i'm stuck because i have no idea how to change color dynamically.

```
public class TableSearchCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    String search = "";

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (table.getValueAt(row, column).equals(search)) {
            setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

I've tried with something like this but it doesn't work.

I tried to call rerender table like this way

```
 String selectedTitle = tabbed.getTitleAt(tabbed.getSelectedIndex());
 JTable table = tabels.get(selectedTitle);

 ((TableSearchCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).setSearch(searchField.getText());
 table.repaint();
 ((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
```

but with no success :(

Could you help me?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How do you handle change events from `searchField`?

Comment: I thought that calling: 
table.repaint();
or
((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
could work(but don't)

Comment: Consider calling `super.getTableCellRendererComponent` in `getTableCellRendererComponent`

Comment: How it could help me? I'm quite new in swing.

Comment: adding super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); doesn't help :(

Comment: `if (table.getValueAt(row, column).equals(search)) {` should be `startsWith(String prefix, int toffset)`, `AbstractTableModel` has nothing to do with your job, nor with internal event `fireTableDataChanged()`, nor with `repaint()`, post an SSCCE, even this question is quite simple and answered here a few times

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version of your search feature based on the TableCellRenderer. One of the issue you may have hit, is that, although your TableModel contains String, if you use the `DefaultTableModel`, it always returns `Object.class` for all data and the `JTable` will therefore use the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` instead of your `TableSearchCellRenderer`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable2 {

    private String search;

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    private class TableSearchRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setBackground(null);
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (getSearch() != null && getSearch().length() > 0 && value.toString().contains(getSearch())) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            return tableCellRendererComponent;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            model.addColumn("Column " + (i + 1));
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
                row.add(WORDS[random.nextInt(WORDS.length)]);
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        table = new JTable(model);
        TableSearchRenderer renderer = new TableSearchRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        textField = new JTextField(30);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateSearch();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateSearch();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateSearch();
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTable2.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void updateSearch() {
        setSearch(textField.getText());
        table.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable2().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static final String[] WORDS = { "art", "australia", "baby", "beach", "birthday", "blue", "bw", "california", "canada", "canon",
            "cat", "chicago", "china", "christmas", "city", "dog", "england", "europe", "family", "festival", "flower", "flowers", "food",
            "france", "friends", "fun", "germany", "holiday", "india", "italy", "japan", "london", "me", "mexico", "music", "nature",
            "new", "newyork", "night", "nikon", "nyc", "paris", "park", "party", "people", "portrait", "sanfrancisco", "sky", "snow",
            "spain", "summer", "sunset", "taiwan", "tokyo", "travel", "trip", "uk", "usa", "vacation", "water", "wedding" };
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;

}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks :)
Could you tell me what i need to change to also change color of line to GREEN?

Comment: @skoczo in your table renderer, you need to check if any value of the row contains the searched word. If it does, set the backgournd to green, else don't.

Comment: Simple and effective. Works with any LAF. +1

Answer (score 1):

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). The example does row level highlighting on a fixed word. You would need to modify the code to do the highlighting on your search word.

Another approach is to filter the table to see only the rows that contain the text you are searching for. See [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I change prepare renderer.

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

                    **if (column == 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                            if (((TableSearchRenderer) getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).getSearch().length() > 0 && ((TableSearchRenderer) getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).getSearch().toLowerCase().equals(getModel().getValueAt(row, i).toString().toLowerCase()))
                                ((TableSearchRenderer) getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).getRows().add(row);
                        }
                    }**

                    if (((TableSearchRenderer) getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).getRows().contains(row) && c.getBackground() != Color.RED) {
                        c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                    return c;
                }
            };
```